# I am getting a Concurrent Modification exception here.Plz suggest how to solve

Tags: android, exception, concurrency

@Override

```
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if(constraint != null) {
            suggestions.clear();
            for (DrugsInfo customer : itemsAll) {
                if(customer.getDRUGNAME().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                    suggestions.add(customer);
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        ArrayList<DrugsInfo> filteredList = (ArrayList<DrugsInfo>) results.values;
        if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            for (DrugsInfo c : filteredList) {
                add(c);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

I am getting a Concurrent Modification exception here.Plz suggest how to solve..

***error in this line  for (DrugsInfo c : filteredList) {***

Comment: There's not enough code here to know for sure.  The error means you have multiple threads trying to read/write a collection at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking at this code:

```
            suggestions.clear();
            for (DrugsInfo customer : itemsAll) {
                if(customer.getDRUGNAME().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                    suggestions.add(customer);
                }
            }
```

and noticing that you are clearing an existing list (which is apparently a class property, not a local variable) rather than creating a new empty list here.  I'm willing to bet that your `suggestions` list is the actual list backing the adapter.  If I'm right, then here's what's happening:

- in `performFiltering()` you assign `suggestions` to `filterResults.values`.  Now `filterResults.values`.  Now `filterResults.values` holds a reference to your adapter source list.
- in `publishResults()` you assign `results.values` (which came from `filterResults.values`) to `filteredList`.  Now `filteredList` holds a reference to the adapter source list.
- Next you create an iterator by running a for-each loop over the list.  So now you have a iterator on the backing list.  The list cannot be modified while the iterator is doing its thing (hence the `ConcurrentModificationException`; you can't modify the list concurrently with an active iterator).
- Then you call `add(c)` which makes the adapter add to the adapter source list -- you know, the one you're now iterating on.
- The iterator now notices that the list has been modified and throws the exception.

I've learned with Android development that *you have to be really careful about assigning lists to other list variables*.  It's too easy to forget that the other variable is really the same list.

You should be able to fix this by changing the code snippet above to:

```
            ArrayList<DrugsInfo> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DrugsInfo customer : itemsAll) {
                if(customer.getDRUGNAME().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                    tempList.add(customer);
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = tempList;
            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
```

Oh, and by the way you can replace this code

```
            for (DrugsInfo c : filteredList) {
                add(c);
            }
```

with

```
            addAll(filteredList);
```